# Неправильные значения в дебаггере с++ android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-debug

Начал изучать NDK и столкнулся с проблемой. При входе дебаггером в метод (при этом не имеет значение, "провалился" я в него или поставил точку останова в нём) в параметрах функции я получаю не те значения, которые ожидаю (например 1-9), а "мусорные" (например -1296364636). При этом все значения, инициализирующиеся в текущем скоупе назначаются переменным корректно (при отладке дебаггером).

Когда я отключаю дебаггер и вывожу значения в лог - я вижу то, что ожидаю (1-9).

Кто нибудь знает, откуда растут ноги у этой штуки и как можно с этим бороться?

---

UPDATED (added code):

Про неточности в коде, которые приводят к неправильному результату не надо говорить абсолютно ничего, пока вылавливаю баги. Речь только дебаггере

На самом деле все проще некуда:
Здесь создаем объект генератора и вызываем функцию genereate. Потом я буду либо класть результат в файл, либо возвращать в джава-код

```
JNICALL
Java_iam_thevoid_sudoku_MainActivity_generate(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    BoardGenerator boardGenerator;
    boardGenerator.generate();
    boardGenerator.printBoard();
    return NULL;
}
```

Сам board generator выглядит так:

```
#ifndef SUDOKU_BOARDGENERATOR_H
#define SUDOKU_BOARDGENERATOR_H


#include "Cell.h"
#include <stack>

#define SMALL_SIZE 3

#define WIDTH (SMALL_SIZE * SMALL_SIZE)
#define HEIGHT (SMALL_SIZE * SMALL_SIZE)


class BoardGenerator {

public:
/**
* Generator
*/
    BoardGenerator();

    void generate();

    void printBoard();

private:

    std::stack<Cell> cellStack;

    Cell board[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    Cell tryPlaceCell(Cell);

    /**
     * Print helpers
     */
    bool isSqrtPrinted(int, int);

    bool isLastPrinted(int, int);

    /**
     * Generate helpers
     */

    int positionInHorizontalLine(int, int);

    int positionInVerticalLine(int, int);

    int xPositionInSquare(int, int, int);

    void increaseX(int *, int *);

    void increaseY(int *, int *);

    void nextSquare(int *, int *);
};


#endif //SUDOKU_BOARDGENERATOR_H
```

Соответственно нас интересует функция generate() и любая из отлаживаемых функций:

```
void BoardGenerator::generate() {
    // Creating random SUDOKU
    srand((unsigned int) time(NULL));

    for (int step = 0; step < WIDTH * HEIGHT; step++) {
        // number (1-9)
        int number = step % WIDTH + 1;
        // rand x
        int nextX = rand() % WIDTH;
        // rand y
        int nextY = rand() % HEIGHT;


        Cell cell = tryPlaceCell(Cell(nextX, nextY, 0, number));

        board[cell.getY()][cell.getX()] = cell;
    }
}
```

tryPlaceCell:

```
Cell BoardGenerator::tryPlaceCell(Cell cell) {

    int nextX = cell.getX(), nextY = cell.getY();

    bool finished = false;

    // attempt. Increase to 81 if it is needed. Avoid endless cycle;
    int attempt = cell.getAttempt();

    if (attempt != 0) {
        increaseX(&nextX, &nextY);
    }

    int number = cell.getNumber();

    // Variable to find offset of attempts for not retry any attempts
    int curX;

    while (attempt++ < WIDTH * HEIGHT) {

        // Number already placed in this Cell
        if (board[nextY][nextX].getNumber() != 0) {
            increaseX(&nextX, &nextY);
            continue;
        }

        // Check if there are no same numbers in horizontal line
        if (positionInHorizontalLine(nextY, number) != -1) {
            curX = nextX;
            attempt += WIDTH - curX - 1;
            increaseY(&nextX, &nextY);
            continue;
        }


        if (xPositionInSquare(nextX, nextY, number) != -1) {
            curX = nextX;
            nextSquare(&nextX, &nextY);
            attempt += nextX == 0 ? WIDTH - curX : nextX - curX;
            continue;
        }

        if (positionInVerticalLine(nextX, number) != -1) {
            increaseX(&nextX, &nextY);
            continue;
        }

        if (attempt < WIDTH * HEIGHT) {
            break;
        }

        finished = true;
    }


    if (finished) {
        Cell cell = cellStack.top();
        cellStack.pop();
        board[cell.getY()][cell.getX()] = Cell();
        tryPlaceCell(cell);
    }

    cellStack.push(Cell(nextX, nextY, attempt, number));

    return cellStack.top();
}
```

А дебаггер входит, например, сюда:

```
int BoardGenerator::positionInHorizontalLine(int y, int value) {
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "tag", "%d %d", y, value);

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        if (board[y][i].getNumber() == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[image: Входим в метод]
[image: Минуем логгер]

Comment: а под отладчиком в лог также выводиться "мусор"? (btw, в с++ нет методов. Только функции).

Comment: @KoVadim , интересное дело, до вывода в лог - мусор, после лога становятся нормальными ) А если без лога, то мусор идет в дальнейшую логику. За методы прошу прощения, это все java мой язык попортил :)

Comment: Показывайте код, вполне возможно, что там есть высящий указатель или другой ub.

Comment: @KoVadim готово. Если что то надо уточнить - добавлю

Comment: Мне сильно не нравиться эта строка `attempt += nextX == 0 ? WIDTH - curX : nextX - curX;` - я думаю, что она выполняется не так, как Вы ожидаете.

Comment: @KoVadim там много чего написано неправильно, но так уж я подхожу к разработке. Сначала придумываю, потом начинаю делать, потом понимаю, что предусмотрел не все и начинаю импровизировать. А потом получается костяк с кучей багов, который я отлаживаю :) Алгоритм не рабочий на данный момент- это факт, но вопрос о другом. Нет ли у Вас идей, почему таким образом работает дебаггер?

Comment: К сожалению, телепатия у меня не всегда работает. По указанным кускам пока багу не видно

Comment: То же самое было, до того, как я растащил все это на классы. Может надо что то добавить в gradle?